# How do I remove a row from table populated through foreach - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using foreach to populate the table data.

I was using the tr length to calculate of find the total rows yielded through foreach result. 
Once I get the length, I am then appending a new row by increment the value

I added index of the foreach result to the id so that the elements have id when they are populated

```
@foreach ($products as $index => $items)
    <tr id="addr{{$index}}">
@endforeach
```

***Issue 1:***

When I am trying to increment, the value is skipped by 1.

Still I am able to add new rows.

***Issue 2:***

I am unable to remove the rows populated through foreach

```js
$(function (){ 
    var inc = $('#tab_logic tbody tr').length;
// var inc = i;
console.log("first" + inc);
$("#add_row_edit").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
$("#tab_logic").append('<tr id="addr' + (inc + 1) + '"></tr>');
$("#addr" + (inc + 1)).html($("#addr0").html());
inc++
console.log("second" + inc);

// $trNew.find(':input[disabled]').prop('disabled', false);
// $trNew.find(':input').val('');
});
$("#delete_row_edit").click(function () {
    // console.log("third" + inc);
    if (inc > 1) {
                $("#addr" + (inc)).remove();
                inc--;
            }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tab_logic" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead class="orange ">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                HSN Code
                            </th>
                            <th class="center">
                                GST
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Quantity
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Rate(per Nos)
                            </th>
                            
                            <th>
                                Amount
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tab_logic_body">
                                                                                                <tr id="addr0">
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="product_name autocomplete" placeholder="" value="Full Product Name" disabled="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="2" class="product_id">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="text" class="hsn_code autocomplete" placeholder="" value="HSN24">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="hsn_code_id[]" class="hsn_code_id" value="6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="text" class="gst autocomplete" placeholder="GST" name="gst[]" readonly="readonly" value="24">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="gst_price" value="24">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter Qty" class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0" value="1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="number" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" class="form-control product_price" step="0" min="0" value="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="number" name="row_total_amount[]" placeholder="Total Amount" class="form-control row_total_amount" step="0" min="0" readonly="readonly" value="118">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                                                                                <tr id="addr1">
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="product_name autocomplete" placeholder="" value="Product Name Exclusive" disabled="">
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1" class="product_id">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="text" class="hsn_code autocomplete" placeholder="" value="HSN18">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="hsn_code_id[]" class="hsn_code_id" value="5">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="text" class="gst autocomplete" placeholder="GST" name="gst[]" readonly="readonly" value="18">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="gst_price" value="18">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter Qty" class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0" value="1">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="number" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" class="form-control product_price" step="0" min="0" value="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                <div class="col s12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                                            <input type="number" name="row_total_amount[]" placeholder="Total Amount" class="form-control row_total_amount" step="0" min="0" readonly="readonly" value="118">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                                                        
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
                
                <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    <th class="right">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn z-depth-1" id="add_row_edit"><i
                                                class="material-icons">add_box</i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn z-depth-1 red" id="delete_row_edit"><i
                                                class="material-icons">remove</i> </button>
                                    </th>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                </table>
```

Screenshot attached

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember

Array starts from index 0

So when you have array like `var a = [1,2,3]`. It will have data on 0,1,2 index and length of array will be 3.

You have misunderstood this in your code

When you are adding data on array always use `.length` not `.length + 1`.
You have used `.length + 1` while adding.

And while removing always use `.length - 1`. You have used `.length`
I have edited your code

```js
$(function() {
  
  // var inc = i;
  $("#add_row_edit").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    var inc = $('#tab_logic tbody tr').length;
    $("#tab_logic").append('<tr id="addr' + (inc) + '"></tr>');
    $("#addr" + (inc)).html($("#addr0").html());
    inc++
    console.log("second" + inc);

    // $trNew.find(':input[disabled]').prop('disabled', false);
    // $trNew.find(':input').val('');
  });
  $("#delete_row_edit").click(function() {
    // console.log("third" + inc);
    var inc = $('#tab_logic tbody tr').length;
    if (inc > 1) {
      $("#addr" + ($('#tab_logic tbody tr').length - 1)).remove();
      inc--;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tab_logic" id="tab_logic">
  <thead class="orange ">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Product Name
      </th>
      <th>
        HSN Code
      </th>
      <th class="center">
        GST
      </th>
      <th>
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th>
        Rate(per Nos)
      </th>

      <th>
        Amount
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tab_logic_body">
    <tr id="addr0">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="product_name autocomplete" placeholder="" value="Full Product Name" disabled="">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="2" class="product_id">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="text" class="hsn_code autocomplete" placeholder="" value="HSN24">
              <input type="hidden" name="hsn_code_id[]" class="hsn_code_id" value="6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="text" class="gst autocomplete" placeholder="GST" name="gst[]" readonly="readonly" value="24">
              <input type="hidden" class="gst_price" value="24">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter Qty" class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0" value="1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="number" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" class="form-control product_price" step="0" min="0" value="100">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="number" name="row_total_amount[]" placeholder="Total Amount" class="form-control row_total_amount" step="0" min="0" readonly="readonly" value="118">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="addr1">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="product_name autocomplete" placeholder="" value="Product Name Exclusive" disabled="">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="1" class="product_id">
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="text" class="hsn_code autocomplete" placeholder="" value="HSN18">
              <input type="hidden" name="hsn_code_id[]" class="hsn_code_id" value="5">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="text" class="gst autocomplete" placeholder="GST" name="gst[]" readonly="readonly" value="18">
              <input type="hidden" class="gst_price" value="18">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="number" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter Qty" class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0" value="1">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="number" name="product_price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" class="form-control product_price" step="0" min="0" value="100">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="number" name="row_total_amount[]" placeholder="Total Amount" class="form-control row_total_amount" step="0" min="0" readonly="readonly" value="118">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <th class="right">
          <button type="button" class="btn z-depth-1" id="add_row_edit"><i
                                                class="material-icons">add_box</i>
                                        </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn z-depth-1 red" id="delete_row_edit"><i
                                                class="material-icons">remove</i> </button>
        </th>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete row using jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "a.deleteRow", function () {
        $(this).closest("td").parent("tr").remove();
        calc_total();
        serialNumber();
    });
```

Comment: 'a.deleteRow' is anchor tag with deleterow id '<a href="javascript:;" class="deleteRow btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete this record"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'